# Passing objects from smartphone app to Arduino through bluetooth

Tags: arduino, windows-mobile, arduino-ide

I'm writing a windows mobile app that connects to an Arduino board.
Currently in order to pass data i'm sending strings from and to the Arduino board.

Is there a way to pass objects or formatted data?

Answer (score 0):

you could use json, which is very easily parsable on the mobile phone side.

it all depends on the kind of data you want to send.

Answer (score 0):

As the arduino is a simple C++ device, you may go with a c structure or a binary object. If you are connecting from windows mobile OS <=6.5.3, you can write in c++ or c# (or vb). You can then use a serialized to convert from/to a structure/object. How many data do you need to transfer? And what types?